# signature verification fails when using diacritic in xml

Tags: digital-signature, xades4j

I used [xades4j](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j) library for xml digital signature. Everything seems ok with signature, but I realized that verification fails if xml file has special letters or accents that are not from English alphabet, such as é or ñ. I used this [code](https://gist.github.com/JohnnyJosep/29cd545db3d0b7abd23279b56d4db194) for digital signing and verification, and here is sample xml which fails to verify after signing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<collection Id="root">
    <album>
        <title>Questions, unanswered</title>
        <artist>Steve and the flubberblubs</artist>
        <year>1989</year>
        <t:tracks xmlns:t="http://test.xades4j/tracks">
            <t:song tracknumber="1" length="4:05">
                <t:title>What do you know?</t:title>
                <t:artist>Steve é flubberblubs</t:artist>
                <t:lastplayed>2006-10-17-08:31</t:lastplayed>
            </t:song>
            <t:song tracknumber="2" length="3:45">
                <t:title>Who do you know?</t:title>
                <t:artist>Steve and the flubberblubs</t:artist>
                <t:lastplayed>2006-10-17-08:35</t:lastplayed>
            </t:song>
            <t:song tracknumber="3" length="5:14">
                <t:title>When do you know?</t:title>
                <t:artist>Steve and the flubberblubs</t:artist>
                <t:lastplayed>2006-10-17-08:39</t:lastplayed>
            </t:song>
            <t:song tracknumber="4" length="4:19">
                <t:title>Do you know?</t:title>
                <t:artist>Steve and the flubberblubs</t:artist>
                <t:lastplayed>2006-10-17-08:44</t:lastplayed>
            </t:song>
        </t:tracks>
    </album>
</collection>
```

Exception I get is:

```
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Verification failed for URI "#root"
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Expected Digest: KHQDbFVesKu/iTx7o1ad80ADwyDo1/sw/bagFpPMNH0=
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Actual Digest: S+7XIBhTeXQZ8UOdz1e2gbM1mJFrN9c/pEForMZw0p4=
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Verification failed for URI "#root"
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Expected Digest: KHQDbFVesKu/iTx7o1ad80ADwyDo1/sw/bagFpPMNH0=
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Actual Digest: S+7XIBhTeXQZ8UOdz1e2gbM1mJFrN9c/pEForMZw0p4=
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Verification failed for URI "#root"
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Expected Digest: KHQDbFVesKu/iTx7o1ad80ADwyDo1/sw/bagFpPMNH0=
[main] WARN org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Actual Digest: S+7XIBhTeXQZ8UOdz1e2gbM1mJFrN9c/pEForMZw0p4=
Exception in thread "main" xades4j.verification.ReferenceValueException: Reference '#root' cannot be validated
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.doCoreVerification(XadesVerifierImpl.java:313)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:195)
    at xadesTest.Test2.verifyBes(Test2.java:184)
    at xadesTest.Test2.main(Test2.java:84)
```

If diacritic mark is removed from xml verification is successful. I don't know if code is missing anything or there's somewhere else problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems worth investigating. There are some tests cases that include special characters in signed properties (which are also signed): https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/test/xml/document.signed.t.bes.ptcc.xml. Could this be something related to encoding? Can you try to investigate if there are any options regarding the encoding on the document builder / factory ?

Comment: You were right about document builder factory, adding this part of code solved the problem:
`InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(SIGNED);
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(iStream, "utf-8");
     InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
     is.setEncoding("utf-8");`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for share your solution, it resolved my problem for verify XAdES signature:

```
    InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(SIGNED);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(iStream, "utf-8");
    InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
    is.setEncoding("utf-8");

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

   //Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(SIGNED)));
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    .........
```